# Mongo get results in order of maximum matches of value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've a Document like this:

```
{
   {
      name: 'The best book'
   },

   {
      name: 'The book is the best on Sachin'
   },

   {
      name: 'Best book on Sachin Tendulkar'
   }

}
```

I've search regex mongo query:

```
db.getCollection('books').find({ $in: [/sachin/i, /tendulkar/i, /best/i, /book/i]})
```

It's giving results, but as per my requirement it should give results in sorted order of maximum matches:

```
{
    name: 'Best book on Sachin Tendulkar'      (4 matches)
},
{
    name: 'The book is the best on Sachin'     (3 matches)  
},
{
    name: 'The best book'                       (2 matches)
}
```

I'm new to mongo. Please help me in writing the mongo query for getting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet may be to use the aggregation framework (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/) in this case.
I'd do it like this.

1. Split text into an array of words
2. Intersect the array of tags you want to match with the array produced in step 1.
3. Project the size of the intersection into a field
4. Sort by the field projected in step 3.

Something along these lines

```
db.books.aggregate([
    {$match: {}},
    {$project: {
        name: {$toLower: "$name"},
        ... any other amount of fields ...
    }},
    {$project: {
        name: true,
        ... any other amount of fields ...
        wordArray: {$split: ["$name", " "]}
    }},
    {$project: {
        name: true,
        ... any other amount of fields ...
        wordArray: true,
        numberOfMatches: {
            $size: {
                $setIntersection: ["$wordArray", ["best", "book"]]
            }
        }
    }},
    {$sort: {
        numberOfMatches: -1
    }}
]);
```

Keep in mind that you can put a condition where `$match: {}` is, and filter the initial set of books you're classifying.

I'm not sure if this works with regular expressions though, so I added the first $project phase as a way to ensure you're always comparing lowercase to lowercase

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about $split operator. Though will setIntersection ignore case of strings during comparison? And second thing which I think about is substring match which will work with regex (`books` will match `/book/`). Lets see whether OP needs substring match here

Comment: setIntersection will not ignore the case, it will match the exact case. But in any case (see what I did there) OP can lowercase to whole name string before matching adding a project phase before the $split

Comment: @lascort: Thanks for the answer & it sounds the perfect one. $split is applicable for mongod >= 3.4 version. My app running on heroku, which is running on mongod 3.2. Any idea how can we split for $lte 3.2.12. On running with 3.2, it's giving $split invalid operator.

Comment: I ran query suggest ed by lascort and it ran perfectly with mongo 3.4 version where $split works. Can anyone help me in finding alternate of $split for version less than 3.4